# jQuery / Javascript - Show / hide ID if current url contains /foo/

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery currently and I am looking for a way to hide  if the url contains /blah/.

Thanks in advance for your help. I am a js Noob and know it can be accomplished with regex somehow but don't have the time to learn this right now. I have a deadline I need to meet!

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: What are you wanting to hide? An `a` element whose `href=` matches a url? Or are you looking to hide an element on the page if the page's url matches?

Comment: hide...what? A div? The entire page? Do you want notified so you can hide yourself in a closet...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think he wants to hide an element if the URL contains that part.

```
if (/\/blah\//.test(window.location)) {
    $('#element').hide();
}
```

Comment: Hi There. You are on the money. only if the url contains /blah/ would I hide the element. In your example, what does .test represent?
Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, no problem. `/\/blah\//` is a Regex object that searches for any occurrence of '/blah/'. `test()` is a Regex function that tests to see if the argument has a match to that regex. So if `window.location` contains '/blah/', then execute the following code.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here you go:

Hide 'my_other_id' if the url contains 'foo'

```
if ($('a[href*=foo']).size() > 0) $('#my_other_id').hide();
```

If you want to do this when the page loads, use this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  if ($('a[href*=foo']).size() > 0) {
    $('#my_other_id').hide(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Corey, I rewrote the answer based a little more on what it seems you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Everyone and thank you for your responses. For some reason it did not save my whole message..... Weird!

The full version went more like this:

Hi Folks,

I am using jQuery currently and I am looking for a way to hide an element if the url contains /blah/.

```
if the url contains /foo/ addClass to <div id="blah"></div> so the class is added like <div id="blah newclass"></div> then I can write css for .newclass {display:none;}
```

I hope this makes more sense. I'm going to hop in and try your suggestions now. THANK YOU!