# Hide div when URL contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I want to hide the slider (and a bit more) if someone uses the search module on my Joomla site and tried several solutions mentioned here on stackoverflow like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760605/1641903

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<script>
if (/\/search\//.test(window.location)) {
    $('#hideonsearch').hide();
}
</script>
```

I wrapped the slider in `<div id="hideonsearch>` and tried mentioned jquery in both the body and head (just to be sure), but it doesn't seem to work as you guys can see [here](http://wvg.lexerim.com/component/search/?searchword=zfs&searchphrase=all&Itemid=101).

Any idea on how to get in working?

Comment: Check your console for errors. `$ is not defined `. You've got different versions of jQuery included

Comment: Joomla puts jquery in no conflict mode so try changing `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: You need to position your hide function after jquery, preferable in the $(document).ready function to guarantee jquery is ready

Comment: You are wrapping that script in a dom ready event right?

Comment: @Spokey Yes, works, thanks!

Comment: @RGraham I'll check the console and my code, thanks!

Comment: Also, `window.location` is an object. You'll probably want to run your regex against `location.href`.

Comment: @christian314159 RegExp.test takes a string as a parameter. In the type conversion `toString()` will be called, returning the `.href` property. tl;dr - `window.location` is fine :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You never stop learning ;)

Comment: @Spokey I guess I was a scrolled view - the change didn't work. Code should be `<script>
if (/\/search\//.test(window.location)) {
    jQuery('#hideonsearch').hide();
}
</script>` right?

Comment: @3rror404 I think so as adding `window.addEvent('domready',function(){ ... }` didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw in your web site that the jquery is not loaded when your code is being executed.

You must put your code in the "onload" function, or make sure the jquery is loaded before doing this.

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (/\/search\//.test(window.location)) {
        jQuery('#hideonsearch').hide();
    }
};
```

Or you can use the pure javascript code that is better.

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (/\/search\//.test(window.location)) {
        document.getElementById("hideonsearch").style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

I saw another error in your web site now, related to this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
});
```

error:

> undefined is not a function

And it is related to the same problem, jQuery is not loaded, so you can use "window.onload".

Comment: First thanks for noticing that error - will get right to it! The slider doesn't hide yet though. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @RaimondvanMouche I edited the answer, I think the second way will work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Jacobi, it doesn't seem to work. I honestly have no idea why but it doesn't (I deleted the everywhere and my javascript is on)...

Comment: Sorry its because your div is not loaded yet, so try add the code in the "onload" of the body, like this ---> onload = "((/\/search\//.test(window.location)) ? document.getElementById('hideonsearch').style.display = 'none':'')"

Comment: Not 100% sure if I understand you correct, but changing the div in `<div id="hideonsearch" onload = "((/\/search\//.test(window.location)) ? document.getElementById('hideonsearch').style.display = 'none':'')">` doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: @RaimondvanMouche Not in the div, I forgot that on load doesn't work in "div" components, put in the body.

Comment: Hi @RaimondvanMouche, I saw that your code is the first this in the "body", try putting this after the div "hideonsearch".

Comment: Hi @Jacobi, I just put the code directly after the div and that works, thanks! The onload isn't necessarily then :)

Comment: Hi @RaimondvanMouche, good to know. I make some test here with the second option, and it works for me adding the "window.onload".

Comment: Hi @Jacobi, Ah nice - don't currently get the changed version at work but since `<div id="hideonsearch"> ... </div>` followed by `<script>
if (/\/search\//.test(window.location)) {
    document.getElementById("hideonsearch").style.display = "none";
}
</script>` works I'm happy - thanks man! :)